# Stop the response from writing a file when there is an access denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code

```
try
{        
    GetFileAndDisplay() // Gets the file from the server and writes the file in a Response stream
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error')</script>");
    Response.Clear();                
    Response.ContentType = "";               
    Response.End();                
}
```

The file still gets downloaded for the client, albeit a corrupted file but is there a way to stop the file from downloading.

Comment: Do you also have a problem with your code or something you want to ask about it?

Comment: @Kristof no there is no problem with the code. The error gets caught but the file still gets downloaded

Comment: What file is getting downloaded? Where do you download the file? What is the exception? Also, show the `GetFileAndDisplay()` code.

Comment: Can't you just delete the file on catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{        
    GetFileAndDisplay() // Gets the file from the server and writes the file in a Response stream
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error')</script>");
    Response.Clear();                
    Response.Redirect("path/to/some/page/that/tells/the/user/something/is/wrong")
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to redirect the user

Comment: Then what do you want to happen for him?

Comment: I guess ill just keep it simple and redirect them. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

As you are catching an UnauthorizedAccessException why not throw a HttpException with a relevant HTTP status code (i.e a 401) -

```
throw new HttpException(401, ex.Message);
```